# Flutter Firestore Cache

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I try to reduce connections to FireStore in my Flutter App & use cached data until I add a new item (Provider.of(context, listen: false).synced = false; - to resync).

Then pass: **source: synced == true ? Source.cache : Source.serverAndCache** to **getDocuments()**

Now all data fetch only the first time & when I need it.

But maybe there is a much more elegant way? What the right way to reduce connections & reduce costs.

I Use this code in my Task repository:

```
class TaskRepository extends BaseRepository {
  String status;
  bool synced;

  TaskRepository() {
    ref = db.collection('tasks');
  }

  Future<List<Task>> fetchDocuments() async {
    List<Task> documents;

    await ref
        .where('ownerUID', isEqualTo: await Auth.getUID())
        .where('status', isEqualTo: status ?? 'assigned')
        .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
        .getDocuments(source: synced == true ? Source.cache : Source.serverAndCache)
        .then((result) {
      documents = result.documents.map((doc) {
        print(doc.metadata.isFromCache ? "Task from CACHE" : "Task from NETWORK");
        synced = true;
        return Task.fromMap(doc.data, doc.documentID);
      }).toList();
    }).catchError((error) {
      print('Error: $error');
    });

    return documents;
  }
}
```

And BaseRepository

```
class BaseRepository with ChangeNotifier {
  final Firestore db = Firestore.instance;
  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  bool debug = true;
  CollectionReference ref;
  DateTime now = DateTime.now();

  BaseRepository() {
    db.settings(persistenceEnabled: true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been building Flutter applications using Firebase for a while and this was one of my principal concerns when I started.

After 2 months trying different things I decided to cache the data as you do so I think it is clear and shouldn’t be any problem.